# Intersection of two circle orthogonally.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The Circle $x^2+y^2+2g_{1}x-a^2 = 0$ and $x^2+y^2+2g_{2}x-a^2=0$ cut each other orthogonally.

If $p_{1}$ and $p_{2}$ are perpendiculars from $(0,a)$ and $(0,-a)$ on common tangent of these

circle. Then prove that $p_{1}p_{2} = a^2$

$\bf{My\; Try::}$ If Two Circle Intersect each other, Then using condition of orthogonality,

we get $g_{1}g_{2} = -a^2........................(1)$

Now Solving $x^2+y^2+2g_{1}x-a^2 = 0$ and $x^2+y^2+2g_{2}x-a^2 = 0,$ we get $x=0$ and $y=\pm a$

So $(0,\pm a)$ are common point on these two circle.

Now Let equation of common tangent is $y=mx+c\Rightarrow mx-y+c=0$

So Length of perpendicular $\displaystyle p_{1} = \left|\frac{c-a}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\right|$

and So Length of perpendicular $\displaystyle p_{2} = \left|\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\right|$

So product $\displaystyle p_{1}\cdot p_{2} = \left|\frac{c-a}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\right|\cdot \left|\frac{c+a}{\sqrt{1+m^2}}\right|=\frac{c^2-a^2}{1+m^2}................(2)$

Now How can I solve after that, Help Required

Thanks

Comment: If the circles intersect perpendicularly at P, the two radii at the intersection are perpendicular.  It may be easier to attack the resulting right triangle.

Answer (score 2):

Just use, the square of distance between the centers is the sum of the squares of the radii.

$$d^2 = r_1^2 + r_2^2$$